# How do I change changing the default program when plugging in removeable media?

Tags: upgrade

I have updated to ubuntu 11.10. The problem is when I plug in my external harddisk,all the files are trying to get opened with movie player. Also when I click the icon of external harddisk which shows up automatically when we plug in external harddisk in the right side panel, movie player opens up and try to open the files in it.

How can I change this default opening program from movie player to file browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seen here & some variations of were fixed in a nautilus upgrade & should no longer be an issue, at least thru 12.04

report, fix shown here

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/876788

Answer (score 4):

The default application preferences for removable media can all be set by going to System Settings->Removable Media

[image]

Comment: Actually main problem is clicking on the icon of external harddisk in the tray opens movie player. The right click option over the icon gives only open, keep in launcher, unmount options. Also I have tried by enabling the option "Never prompt or start programs on media insertion" in System Settings->Removable Media. It dint help me.

Comment: I think this answers the question. Perhaps the question should be edited.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer seems outdated. It is now placed in the _info_ section of System Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Click on [image: The gear icon], then on <kbd>About this computer...</kbd> or open <kbd>System Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Details</kbd>.

You will get a window like the one below, where you select the option **Removable Media** in the list view on the left.

[image: screenshot]

Now you may chose a suitable action for each listed type of removable media in the drop-down lists on the right. I personally prefer to be asked.