# Default media behavior

Tags: 11.10, gnome, banshee, multimedia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change changing the default program when plugging in removeable media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79920/how-do-i-change-changing-the-default-program-when-plugging-in-removeable-media)

I am using 11.10 with GNOME Shell.

When I insert an audio CD - it opens up Banshee.  I would like it to open up Exaile.  I have set Exaile as the default media player using system settings->Default Applications but it does seen to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System Settings > Removable Media`

You can then select how media should be handled.