# How to change default behavior when iPod is plugged in?

Tags: 12.10, rhythmbox, default-programs, ipod, system-settings

Right now when I plug in my iPod, Clementine opens and starts playing, which is annoying because I prefer to manage my iPod using Rhythmbox which has a "sync" feature that Clementine (AFAIK) is missing.

Once upon a time, in some previous version of Ubuntu, you used to be able to change this by going into **Nautilus › Edit › Preferences**, and choosing the **Media** tab. Sometime between then and now (12.10), this tab has gone away, and I cannot find anything about its replacement.

[This Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/79924/1457) on another question suggests there should be a **Removable Media** menu in **System Settings**, but this is also missing for me.

Any idea where the **Removable Media** menu (or its equivalent) is located in 12.10?

Comment: I appreciate folks helping to edit the question, but my question really was about the change between the old version of Ubuntu and the new one rather than just how to use Rhythmbox in place of Clementine. That was the motivation for the question, but I'm much more interested in the general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! In **System Settings > Details > Removable Media** that same old menu can be found, where you can adjust all of the default applications for various types of removable media, e.g. Music players, CDs, DVDs, photos...